# Comparator issue in ocpjp sample questions

Tags: java, java-7, comparator, ocpjp

I am currently preparing for Java SE 7 Programmer exam and I tried to solve the sample questions on the Oracle site. I got stuck at this one:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Primes2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] primes = {2, 7, 5, 3};
            MySort ms = new MySort();
            Arrays.sort(primes, ms);
            for(Integer p2: primes)
                System.out.print(p2 + " ");
        }
     static class MySort implements Comparator {
         public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
             return y.compareTo(x);
         }
     }
}
```

What is the result?

A) 2 3 5 7

B) 2 7 5 3

C) 7 5 3 2

D) Compilation fails.

E) An exception is thrown at run time.

The question can be found here: http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=303&p_certName=SQ1Z0_804

The correct answer indicated on the site is C. I tested the code and found it did not compile, because Comparator is parameterized and in the given code the type was not indicated, therefore the compiler expected Object parameters for compare method. When I changed Comparator with `Comparator<Integer>`, the error was solved and it worked as expected.

My question is whether that declaration in the original code respects the standards of Java 7 and *should* compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, that does not compile.

In order to be valid, either `Comparator` must be typed as `Comparator<Integer>` or `compare()` methods arguments must be of `Object` Type.

Thus, this exam question is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The question is valid and the right answer is "D) Compilation fails".

If you check the page page with the questions you can find the answers at the bottom of it, and for this question is marked D